# 7 days after mobile authentication, still getting 15 day hold.

Tags: steam

I've had the  mobile authenticator on for 7 days as of an hour ago, yet i still get a 15 day hold on any trade. I do not have trade confirmation options in my privacy settings on my phone nor on the steam browser itself. This is extremely frustrating and steam support keeps giving me bullshit automated answers. anyone help?

Comment: Have you been trying to trade with the same person, or different ones? If it's the same person that person might not have it activated so the hold will still apply

Comment: its with anyone or any bot i try to trade with...

Answer (score -1):

You have to wait for a while before it works again without the hold. One time I had it on and I was waiting for it and eventually it worked, no hold.